# How to select siblings in tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I want to create an output like

Home / Library / Data

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="st-breadcrumb">
    <div class="st-breadcrumb-default"></div>
    <div class="st-breadcrumb-item">Home</div>
    <div class="st-breadcrumb-item active">Library</div>
    <div class="st-breadcrumb-item">Data</div>
</div>
```

Here is my css in tailwind css
.

```
st-breadcrumb-item ~ .st-breadcrumb-item:before {
  content: '/';
  margin: '10px';
}
```

Did I miss something or I need to have settings somewhere in config?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

##### HTML

```
<div>
  <div className={"st-breadcrumb"}>
    // "your default div deleted"
    <div className={"st-breadcrumb-item"}>Home</div>
    <div className={"st-breadcrumb-item active"}>Library</div>
    <div className={"st-breadcrumb-item"}>Data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### CSS

```
.st-breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.st-breadcrumb-item ~ .st-breadcrumb-item::before {
  content: "/";
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It works. But is there a way to register it as variant in tailwind config?

Answer (score 1):

**Tailwind v2.2+** has built-in support for [siblings](https://blog.tailwindcss.com/tailwindcss-2-2#sibling-selector-variants) called `peer` but it works with pseudo-classes not pseudo-elements. Simplest solution will be this structure for Tailwind v2.2 (as it is has support for `after`) with `mode: 'jit'` enabled in your config.

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="after:content-['/'] after:mx-2.5">Home</div>
    <div data-separator='/' class="after:content-[attr(data-separator)] after:mx-2.5">Library</div>
    <div class="">Data</div>
</div>
```

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.export = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: {
        content: [
            // files to watch
        ],
    },
}
```

DEMO: https://play.tailwindcss.com/bXQTNZtkMI

**For older versions** you can use plugins like [tailwindcss-pseudo-elements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-pseudo-elements) which will add support for `before` and `after`. With this plugin you need to extend variants in your config and define content as `tw-content-after="/"`

```
<div class="flex">
    <div tw-content-after="/" class="after:mx-2.5">Home</div>
    <div tw-content-after="/" class="after:mx-2.5">Library</div>
    <div class="">Data</div>
</div>
```

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.export = {
    variants: {
        extend: {
            margin: ['after'],
        },
    },
    plugins: [
         require('tailwindcss-pseudo-elements'),
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of label when input is checked, You just needed to add [&:checked+label]:text-red-500 tailwindcss classes and access the siblings.

Yes

More Explain:

```
<div>
    <input id="choice-yes" type="checkbox" class="opacity-0 w-0 fixed [&:checked+label]:text-red-500"/>
    <label for="choice-yes" class="text-blue-50">Yes</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**